How to Change the Appearance of a <MenuButton> in azure-devops-ui/Menu
I'm developing an extension an creating a complete new board for a User Story Mapping. In the card I want to add a menu just like the original board. Here is the example of what to I have so far: User Story Mapping board
I would like to use the <MenuButton> component to create a "more options" button, similar to the one used in the current boards. I need to customize the appearance of the button in the following ways:

Make the button smaller
Change the color on onEnter and onLeave events
Remove the chevron icon

The result would be:
Result expected
I dont want to add an option in the menu but actually create a complete new board.
I would like to know if it is possible to use the Azure Devops UI library or I need to use something else?
Here is a basic example of how I'm using the <MenuButton>:
import { IMenuItem, MenuButton } from "azure-devops-ui/Menu";


<div style={{ width: "25px", height: "25px", position: "absolute", top: "3px", right: "3px", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <MenuButton
            subtle={true}
            iconProps={{ iconName: "More" }}
            className="full-size"
            contextualMenuProps={{
              menuProps: {
                items: menuItems,
                onActivate: handleMenuActivate,
                id: "cardSelectionMenu",
              },
            }}
          />
        </div>

But I go this
bad ux
Im using
dependencies": {
    "azure-devops-extension-api": "~1.157.0",
    "azure-devops-extension-sdk": "~2.0.11",
    "azure-devops-ui": "~2.164.0",
}


Hi I have solve the issue, tks for your help.

It is posible to edit the style with the style prop directly.
and also with hideDropdownIcon=false you hide the chevron.
With size: IconSize.inherit let you change the size of the button

Here its my component
const ButtonCardMenu: React.FC<IProps> = () => {


    const handleActionClick = (action: string) => {
        consoleLogDev(`Action clicked: ${action}`);
    };

    const menuItems: IMenuItem[] = [
        {
            id: "linkdependency",
            text: "Link Dependency",
            onActivate: () => handleActionClick('linkdependency')
        }
    ];


    return (<div style={{ width: "25px", height: "25px", position: "absolute", top: "0px", right: "0px" }}>
        <MenuButton
            hideDropdownIcon={true}
            subtle={true}
            ariaHidden={true}
            iconProps={{ iconName: "More", size: IconSize.inherit }}
            style={{
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(224, 230, 236)',
                border: 'none',
                borderRadius: '1px',
                width: "25px",
                height: "24px"
            }}
            contextualMenuProps={{
                menuProps: {
                    items: menuItems,
                    onActivate: handleMenuActivate,
                    id: "SelectionMenu",
                },
            }}
        />
    </div>)
};

export default ButtonCardMenu;


Glad that the issue can be resolved, and thanks for sharing the solution. Maybe, you can accept this answer by yourself. It could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues. @Julu

To add a menu item to the cards on the Kanban Boards, you need to use the Target ID "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-context-menu" in the vss-extension.json file of your extension.

This item also will show in the menu list if you open the work items.

For more details, you can reference the code here to develop yourself extension. The code is open-source. This sample should have provided the code to set icon and font of the menu item.


tks for your response. I don't want to add an option in the menu but actually create a complete new board call User Story Mapping, and a new card with more options. and there I would like to change the appearance of the button.

@Julu, So, your extension is adding a hub named "User Story Mapping" under the "Azure Boards" hub group. This new hub is a Kanban board to show show the cards of work items. you want to add multiple items in the menu of the cards displayed on the page, and also set the appearance of the items. right?

Yes correct I have already add a hub like this:
{
"contributions": [
{
"id": "UserStoryMapping",
"type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
...
}
and first I want to change the appearance of the button, where I click to open the menu. Mainly I want:

Thats correct I have already created the hub like this
{   "contributions": [     {       "id": "UserStoryMapping",       "type": "ms.vss-web.hub", ...   ] }
And I created a card and add a menu button component <MenuButton> . I would like to change the appearance where I click to open the menu. Mainly:

Make the button smaller
Change the color on onEnter and onLeave events
Remove the chevron icon

If you have and example of how to change the appearance of one particular item, that would be great too, maybe add a toggle button, but that's a second question

@Julu, From the screenshot you provided, I noticed you only have one item added in the menu, can you try to add more items to see if it will automatically adjust the appearance of the items to make them look smaller.
